# jQuery mousedown find exact element on which event get fired

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

Hi I have this HTML code

```
<th scope="col" class="" style="width: 13px;">
   <div class="some-handle"></div>
  <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucPWP$ctl03$3056$GVReport','Sort$3')">Passengers</a>
</th>
```

and have this JS code

```
  $("Table tr th").mousedown(function (e) {  
    /*mousedown code goes here... */
    /* ignore if mousedown occur on div "some-handle" */
  }
```

Now I try to catch if mousedown occur on div having class "some-handle". 
can I do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check [`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target). This is the element where the event originated.

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass('some-handle')) {
    // fired on div "some-handle"
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry - this is NOT the answer to your question. You asked how to prevent things from happening when the element with this class was clicked.

Comment: brilliant answer, didn't know that event will bubble even on child elements!

Comment: @anasnakawa whilst your comment is true about code, the answer accepted by the OP here is not correct at all. openidsujoy
 is saying "ignore" when the object receives a mousedown event. So IMHO it doesn't solve the problem. You couldn't even put an `else` because this would fire on everything, and that's not correct either.

Comment: @T9b The question is how to find the exact element where the event was fired. That is `e.target`. I'm not entirely sure what the OP wants (the question is hardly clear), but the solution will almost certainly include `e.target`. My code works with the HTML provided.

Comment: @lonesomeday I agree the questioner has not made it clear and has *also* asked how to identify the mousedown on the element with the class. But my point is that `/* ignore if mousedown occur on div "some-handle" */ ` is not the same as `// fired on div "some-handle" `, and my argument is that even though he can identify the event from your code - it would be useless because he actually needs to process soemthing else. I'd like to have the OP reply to this discussion, and answer how he was able to use your code to "ignore" the event was triggered, or else he should select another answer.

Comment: @T9b I would have thought `!` would have done the trick, to be honest.

Comment: @lonesomeday Really? see my comment above. That would fire your code on every element that doesn't have the class. The OP only wants it to fire for the specific table detail.

Comment: @T9b The event is handled on the `Table tr th` selection. You can then decide whether or not to do anything based on whether the originating element has a particular class. I can't see how this doesn't resolve the OP's question.

Comment: @lonesomeday it doesn't answer the OP's question because you constructed a different scenario and then answered it. That's what I'm objecting too. Your last comment shows that the first reply was wrong, because now you admit that a further object needs consideration for it to work. Other answers dealt with that right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
  $("Table tr th").mousedown(function (e) {   

       if ($(this).hasClass('some-handle')) { 
        // ignore
        return False;
        }
        /*mousedown code goes here... */ 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do, is to store a value on the `th` when the mouse is over your `some-handle` div, then to check for this value when the mouse is over `th` element:

```
$("Table tr th").mousedown(function (e) {  
    /*mousedown code goes here... */
    /* ignore if mousedown occur on div "some-handle" */
    if(!$(this).data('overSomeHandle')) {
        // do your code here
    }
}

$('.some-handle').hover(
    function(){
        // we are over some-handle div
        $(this).parent().data('overSomeHandle', true);
    }, 
    function(){
        // we are out of some-handle div
        $(this).parent().data('overSomeHandle', false);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having trouble because you have a link nested into your `<DIV>`. The link click will fire overriding your code I suspect.

Therefore you need to handle the click before you implement the code:

```
$("Table tr th").mousedown(function (e) 
{            
    e.preventDefault(); //this nullifies the click
    if ($(this).hasClass('some-handle')) 
    {          
        // ignore         
        return False;         
    }else{
        /*mousedown code goes here... */          
    }
});
```